# Privileges in docker-compose

Tags: docker

Please help.. I have a docker-compose file that looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  auth:        
    image: 10.10.10.000:5000/my-auth:test
    user: 1234:12345      
    expose:
       - "38090"        
    volumes:
        - "/services/logs/auth:/logs"        
    networks:
        - com        
    environment:
        - AUTH_CHECK_URL=http://someurl
    restart: always
```

I run it with docker-compose up -d. Actually questions:

1. I understand correctly, the logs folder from my service in the container is mounted on the host machine?
2. In the logs folder in the container, upon startup, a log.txt file is created with the rights -rw-r--r-- on behalf of the user and group specified above and is mounted, if I understand correctly, on the host machine. Can I somehow specify in docker-compose that this file is created with the permissions -rw-rw---- ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On question 1: Mounts are *always* in the opposite direction: the directory on the host is mounted into the container.

This has the effect you're looking for, in that writes to the directory in the container are also visible on the host.  The difference here is what happens with content that might have already existed in the host directory or in the image.  If the image contained data in the `/logs` directory, this will always be hidden by the bind mount; if the host directory contained data already, this will be visible in the container.

On question 2: Docker doesn't directly control file permissions or ownership.  It can control what user the container process runs as, but not much more.  The [`docker run` options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/) don't include an option to change things like the umask (a set of permission bits that are turned off in newly created files), nor is there an equivalent Compose setting.

The flip side of this is that, whatever permission the application requests when creating the file, it should work the same way running the program in Docker or not.  If the application tries to create the file with mode 0660 instead of 0644, you should get a consistent result.